# Relationship between ionization energy and orbitals

Tags: electrons, orbitals, ionization-energy

My chemistry book says that the ionization energy depends on the orbital an electron is taken from?

I'm not sure I understand what it means. Could someone please explain this?

Comment: I don't understand it either. Are they talking about one element or different elements, to begin with?

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16186/whats-the-difference-between-ionization-energy-and-orbital-energy